# GRUB2 Boot Loader Wrong Default Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I changed the `/etc/default/grub` file to the following:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=3
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
```

and also `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober` file to the following:

```
if [ "\${timeout}" = 0 ]; then    
  set timeout=0
```

My problem is the following: i wanted the `GRUB_DEFAULT` to start up Ubuntu, but the problem is that `GRUB_DEFAULT=3` points to a windows test memory startup, and with the other modifications, the GRUB2 menu screens skips and goes directly to that partion (Windows Test).

I need to find a way to edit the Ubuntu `/etc/default/grub` and set `GRUB_DEFAULT=3` to `GRUB_DEFAULT=1` or a way to see the GRUB MENU on startup.

Holding shift after boot doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: If the problem is that you can't boot into Ubuntu to edit the files, and if you're booting in EFI mode, try using the USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) to boot into Ubuntu on a one-time basis. You should then be able to edit your GRUB configuration and do a `sudo update-grub` to fix the problem. Alternatively, you could boot an Ubuntu live CD; however, the process for updating GRUB will either be more complex (and therefore error-prone) or involve Boot Repair (which can have unintended side effects).

Comment: Escape key with UEFI normally gets you to a grub menu. But if you have fast boot (not Windows fast start up) on in UEFI you may have to be very quick or it may only work from total cold boot. Or some have to turn off UEFI fast boot to be able to press a key on boot. Do you have multiple Ubuntu installs? or why is not entry 0 as default not the one you want?

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/default/grub` and files in `/etc/grub.d/` are template files which decide how the `update-grub` command creates the `grub` configuration files. You can edit the files in `[boot partition mount point]/grub/grub.cfg` from another OS which can read the `/boot` filesystem (usually `ext4`) including live systems which you start from USB. Just mount your `/boot` filesystem under `[boot partition mount point]` - in doubt which one is the right one check `/etc/fstab`, find the UUID for `/boot` and `mount UUID=[UUID] /mnt/boot` (then edit `/mnt/boot/grub/grub.cfg`).